# Prove that exactly one of the systems has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $A$ be an $m$x$n$ matrix, $B$ $l$x$n$ matrix and $c\in R^n$.
Prove that exactly one of the systems has a solution:

i)$$Ax\leq0,\:\: Bx=0,\:\: c^Tx>0,\:\: x\in R^n$$
ii)$$A^Tp+B^Tq=c,\:\:p\geq0,\:\:p\in R^m,\:\:q\in R^l$$

It's easy to prove that neither can be true at the same time by simply transposing and multiplying by x ii) and the other way around, but how do I show that exactly one must be true?

The hint which does not make much sense to me is to take $q=r-s$ where $r,s\geq0$.

Comment: The hint allows you to only have nonnegative variables in problem (ii) and be exactly in the situation of Farkas' lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(ii)$ has a solution, then $(i)$ can't have a solution.

Now suppose $(ii)$  doesn't have a solution, then the following problem is not feasible:

$$\min 0$$
$$A^Tp + B^Tr-B^Ts = c$$
$$p \ge 0$$
$$r  \ge 0$$
$$s \ge 0$$

Let's consider it's dual.

$$\max c^Tx$$
$$Ax \le 0$$
$$Bx \le 0$$
$$-Bx \le 0$$

Check that it is feasible and conclude that it is unbounded and that should help you to conclude that $(i)$ has a solution.